# Can a Time Lord survive with just one heart?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

In *Doctor Who*, Time Lords such as the Doctor have two hearts, which got me wondering if they need both to survive or if the second heart is so that if one stops working they can still survive (kind of like a backup generator). And if they can survive without one heart working, will it be harmful to them or reduce their physical abilities at all, or can they go on with just the one with no ill effects, for at least a limited time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We see the Doctor survive having one heart stopped in [The Shakespeare Code](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Shakespeare_Code_(TV_story)) (Martha restarts it shortly after)

We see another in [The Power of Three](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-4.htm)

> RESEARCHER: Hospitals are logging a global surge in heart failures. Cardiac arrests.
>   DOCTOR: That's it. Oh! Oh! Oh! Only one heart. Other one's not working.

It seems this isn't a good state for Time Lords, however. As we see in both instances, The Doctor suffers with only one working

> AMY: Okay, how long are you going to last with only one heart?
>   DOCTOR: Not much longer. I need to locate the wormhole portal.

Answer (score 17):

Time Lords (or at least properly educated ones, so perhaps not the Doctor) can voluntarily stop both their hearts and be fine.  Romana demonstrates this in "Destiny of the Daleks."

> **DOCTOR:**  Romana. Ha ha! I thought you were dead.
>   **ROMANA:**  Well, the only way to escape the Daleks was to feign death. It's lucky they didn't know I was a Gallifreyan.
>   **DOCTOR:**  Good girl.
>   **TYSSAN**:  Gallifreyan?
>   **ROMANA:**  Yes, they taught me at school how to stop my hearts.
>   **TYSSAN:**  Hearts? How many have you got?
>   **ROMANA:**  One for casual, one for best.

When both her hearts are stopped, she feigns death but is very much alive.  So exertion may be impossible without at least one ticker running, but it is definitely possible to *be alive* with neither heart pumping at all.

Moreover, in the third *Doctor Who Serial* ("The Edge of Destruction"/"Beyond the Sun"/"In the Ship" are among it's names), the First Doctor is [heard to have only one heart](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Binary_vascular_system).  Some fans and extended universe media ran with the idea that Time Lords only grew a second heart when they regenerated for the first time.  So again we have an instance of a Time Lord functioning with less than two operational hearts.

Comment: I miss Romana. She was so cool

Comment: I think you missed the point of Romana's explanation. "It's lucky they didn't know I was a Gallifreyan" implies that **they did not know she had a second heart**, meaning she was able to stop one heart (the one they were observing) but not the other (so she could stay alive). She does state that she was taught to stop both hearts, but that doesn't necessarily mean at the same time.

Comment: There's a third instance: The 10th doctor goes into hiding and erases his own memory (he genuinely believes himself to be a human teacher). As part of his cover, he stops one of his heart's so he's biologically as close to a human as he can be. He lived for months with only a single heart. [Link](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/John_Smith_(Tenth_Doctor))

Comment: @Flater in general humans (which Galifreans can pass for) have to stop all of our hearts to feign death so she probably has to too

Comment: @Flater I think he underwent a bigger biological change than simply stopping one of his hearts (which we've seen causes him discomfort, even if it doesn't kill him). Didn't the Chameleon Arch thing transform his whole biology into human?

Comment: @Borgh: If that is the case then "It's lucky they didn't know I was a Gallifreyan" is a meaningless statement. But it's referenced as the saving grace.

Comment: Galifreans apparently can survive without a heartbeat, humans can only manage this in short bursts. If they knew she was one they might have done something more drastic to make sure she stayed down.

Comment: It's also possible that Gallifreyans can simply last a bit longer than humans can without a heartbeat, at least long enough to conclude that if they were human, they would be dead.

Comment: @Flater no, Gallifreyans are taught at school how to stop their hearts. That's why being Gallifreyan matters.

Comment: @Nacht: That would mean "It's lucky I'm Gallifreyan" is relevant to mention, but still not "It's lucky **they didn't know** I'm Gallifreyan"

Comment: @Flater: A human with a stopped heart isn't going to get up any time soon. It seems that gallifreyan's can stop their hearts and then presumably restart them and go on their way (I don't recall the episode but the description doesn't suggest medical intervention being needed to get her up again). This would mean that if you find a gallifreyan without a heartbeaet you can't be sure they are dead. If you find a human (or presumably most others) without a heartbeat you can be pretty sure they are dead.

Comment: @Chris: Why is everyone assuming that just because you can stop either of your hearts, that must mean you must stop both of them at the same time?

Comment: @Flater Because in this situation stopping one heart doesn't make a difference. If you have one heart going and pumping blood you will still have a detectable pulse. Your comment suggesting that they were observing the heart but not the right one doesn't feel like it makes sense. If they are able to scan an individual to see into them well enough to find a heart and see whether it is pumping or not why would that ability be usable only on an area a few inches across? More than anything though she talked about being able to stop both hearts.

Comment: More than anything though she said she could stop both hearts. Chekov's gun sort of suggests that if you talk about being able to stop both hearts then that is what happened. If she only stopped one heart I'd expect the dialogue to reflect that. But she is talking about stopping both hearts so coming up with theories as to why she in fact only stopped one heart seems to be looking further than you need to for an explanation. I guess in the long run though we can't be *sure* either of them are right. I think one thing, you think the other. I guess just let the OP decide.

Comment: @Chris: Because **if they didn't know they were looking at a Gallifreyan**, they wouldn't be looking for a second heart. You might _feel_ a pulse, but you wouldn't see that if you just scanned their (human location) heart. When you go to the doctor and tell them your stomach hurts, does the doctor send you in for a full body scan to make sure you don't have a second stomach anywhere in your body? No. Because there is no reasonable expectation for that to be the case. Similarly, they look at the heart of the (alleged) human and see that it has stopped, therefore they conclude it's a dead human.

Comment: @Chris: "both" does not inherently mean "both at the same time". I can both walk and sit, but I can't sit and walk at the same time. If both my friend and me can drive our car, that doesn't mean we can both do so at the same time. I can wink with both eyes, but if I did it with both eyes at the same time, I'd be blinking, not winking. I can both cook and fix cars but that doesn't mean I can't do one without the other. Both me and my wife work in the same hospital, but that doesn't mean we work the same hours. And so on...

Answer (score 7):

This exact scenario occurs in the Eleventh Doctor story "The Power of Three" (Series 7, Episode 4). In that episode, a bunch of black cubes from space (cosmic cubes, if you will) mysteriously arrive on Earth. Their purpose is initially unknown, and the people of Earth eventually forget them, using them as paperweights and such. After a year on Earth, the cubes begin to actually do something, scanning people, glowing, etc. They start sending people into cardiac arrest, including the Doctor. Only one of his hearts fails, though. It is a very painful process for him, as he states that only one heart can keep him alive:

> I can't do it! I need both hearts!

His companion Amy uses a defibrillator to restart his second heart, as seen in this scene (from 0:59 - 1:10):
[Doctor Who - The Power of Three - Funny moments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slxuhUv-HlE)

Comment: It's always fun when you see how characters are able to start a heart (or fail after obsessively trying) using a device made to stop hearts...